# Update in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am using this code snippet to update values in my database :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SAMA-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=advCenter;Integrated Security=True");
string str = "sama@yahoo.com";
SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("select [user_Account] from User in str where [user_Email]=sama@yahoo.com", con);
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("update User set [user_Account]=? WHERE [user_Email=@em]", con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("user_Account",str);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@em",str);
con.Open();
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

but I get this error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.
>   Line 40:             com.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 3):

"User" is a reserved word in SQL.  Wrap the name of the table in square brackets to specify that it's the name of something:

```
[User]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using two separate `SqlCommand` objects?? Absolutely not needed..... I would try to either UPDATE or SELECT - don't mix two totally separate operations into a single call....

Also: you should use parametrized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks, and you should put your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects into using blocks - try this:

```
string updateStmt = 
   "UPDATE dbo.[User] SET [user_Account] = @AccountValue WHERE [user_Email] = @UserEMail;";

using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SAMA-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=advCenter;Integrated Security=True"))
using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(updateStmt, con))
{
   _cmd.Parameters.Add("@AccountValue", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = str;
   _cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserEMail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = str;

    con.Open();
    _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```